# How to find the average types of bikes that a member vs a casual rider uses?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using a dataset that has members and casual users of a bikesharing company. There are electric bikes, classical bikes and docked bikes under the `rideable_type` column. I am trying to find the average number of bike types that a member vs a casual rider use. The `member_casual` column contains the members and casual rider information.

```
SELECT
  member_casual AS member_type,
  AVG (rideable_type/member_casual)
FROM
  (SELECT
    member_casual,
    rideable_type,
    CAST(member_casual AS float64),
    CAST(rideable_type AS float64)
  FROM
  `table`
  )
GROUP BY 
  member_casual
```

I tried tweaking the code to get it to work, however I ran into another problem. I tried using this code:

```
SELECT
  member_casual,
  AVG(bike)
FROM
  (SELECT
    member_casual,
    rideable_type,
    CAST(rideable_type AS int64) AS bike
  FROM
  `table`
  )
GROUP BY
  member_casual
```

Sample of the data table:

| rideable_type | member_casual |
| --- | --- |
| electric_bike | member |
| electric_bike | member |
| electric_bike | casual |
| classic_bike | casual |
| docked_bike | member |

Comment: The error will most likely occur since you try to cast `rideable_type` (what is in some kind a string, i.e. `varchar`) to an `int64`. Why do you try to `CAST` it? This seems all in all not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. However,  when I took out of the subquery, I get a warning that I can't take an AVG of a string. What would be the way to find the AVG of the _rideable_type_ for members and casual riders?

Comment: Could you share dummy sample data of e.g. ten rows? See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) how to put tables into a question.

Comment: Thank you for informing me how to add tables into my posts! this will make it easier to format my questions in the future. However, I don't know if I was doing it right or not, because when I tried to do it the way the link showed, it wound up looking like "|rideable_type|member_casual| |-----------------------| |electric_bike|..." and not a table, hence why I tried putting the table in the code (```) brackets.

Comment: Next time, please also add the expected result, so we know what you are trying to achieve exactly. I guess that would have helped you yourself, too. For what was `SELECT member_casual, AVG(bike)` supposed to do? Show member/casual type and some number, but no bike information? Probably, you wouldn't have written the query thus, had you had the resulting table in mind. Please see my answer on different results you may or may not be after.

Comment: I will keep this in mind when asking questions on this website in the future. Im learning that being more explicit is better and that I also need to better understand what I am trying to achieve as well. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The following query should do the job: It returns the average per type of member and type of bike.

```
SELECT DISTINCT member_casual
, rideable_type
, CAST(CAST(cnt_type AS float) / CAST(cnt_member AS float) AS NUMERIC) AS average
from
(
    SELECT *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY member_casual ORDER BY member_casual) AS cnt_member,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY member_casual, rideable_type ORDER BY member_casual) AS cnt_type
    FROM `table`
) AS t
ORDER BY member_casual
, rideable_type
```

Results for your table shown above: There are three `member` with two electric bikes and one docked bike and there are two `casual` with one electric bike and one classic bike.

```
|---------------|---------------|---------|
| member_casual | rideable_type | average |
|---------------|---------------|---------|
| casual        | classic_bike  | .50     |
| casual        | electric_bike | .50     |
| member        | docked_bike   | .33     |
| member        | electric_bike | .67     |
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot, I will try and apply what you wrote to the whole of the dataset. I tried to upvote your comment, but it says that I need 15 reputation to do so, but that the vote had been recorded.

Comment: You're welcome and you now should have enough reputation. If your question is answered, please also consider marking the answer as accepted, if it solves your problem. Otherwise just tell me if there is something not clear.

Comment: When I applied your code in BigQuery, I had to change a few things. But it says that "Parameterized types are not allowed in CAST expressions." Would you know what that means?

Comment: And you are right, I do have enough reputation now to upvote your helpful advice.

Comment: Does it work to change the `numeric(3, 2)` to `NUMERIC` (or `BIGNUMERIC`)?

Comment: Yes! it does work when I change the numeric(3, 2) to NUMERIC! thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown the expected result. It sounds like you want to get something like this:

| member_type | electric_bike | classic_bike | docked_bike |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| member | 66.6 | 0.0 | 33.3 |
| casual | 50.0 | 50.0 | 0.0 |

So, for members it is 66.6% riding electric bikes, 33.3% riding docked bikes and 0% riding classic bikes, while for casuals it is 50% electric bikes, 50% classic bikes and 0% docked bikes.

For this query result you must know the bike types in advance, which you use in conditional aggregation expressions:

```
SELECT
  member_casual AS member_type,
  AVG(CASE WHEN rideable_type = 'electric_bike' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS electric_bike,
  AVG(CASE WHEN rideable_type = 'classic_bike'  THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS classic_bike,
  AVG(CASE WHEN rideable_type = 'docked_bike'   THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS docked_bike
FROM mytable
GROUP BY member_casual;
```

If you don't know the bike types in advance, you can only get the data in rows. One way to get that result is:

```
SELECT
  member_casual AS member_type,
  rideable_type,
  COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY member_casual) AS percentage
FROM mytable
GROUP BY member_casual, rideable_type;
ORDER BY member_casual, rideable_type;
```

which leaves out combinations with a count of zero:

| member_type | rideable_type | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| casual | classic_bike | 50.0 |
| casual | electric_bike | 50.0 |
| member | docked_bike | 33.3 |
| member | electric_bike | 66.6 |

If you want to incude the zero counts, you'll have to create all combinations first:

```
SELECT
  mt.member_casual AS member_type,
  rt.rideable_type,
  COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY mt.member_casual) AS percentage
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT member_type FROM mytable) AS mt
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT rideable_type FROM mytable) AS rt
LEFT JOIN mytable t ON t.member_type = mt.member_type
                   AND t.rideable_type = rt.rideable_type
GROUP BY mt.member_casual, rt.rideable_type;
ORDER BY mt.member_casual, rt.rideable_type;
```

resulting in

| member_type | rideable_type | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| casual | classic_bike | 50.0 |
| casual | docked_bike | 0.0 |
| casual | electric_bike | 50.0 |
| member | classic_bike | 0.0 |
| member | docked_bike | 33.3 |
| member | electric_bike | 66.6 |

But in the end you may want something else completely. If we look at the total number of people it is

| member_type | rideable_type | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| casual | classic_bike | 20.0 |
| casual | electric_bike | 20.0 |
| member | docked_bike | 20.0 |
| member | electric_bike | 40.0 |

getting a total of 100%. If it is this or something similar what you want, you need an entirely different query again.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the feedback, I guess I was still trying to understand what I was trying to achieve myself. In that case, I will need to better understand what I am trying to achieve and format my questions better, so that I can get better feedback. Again, thank you so much for the help and your explanations do help me better understand how to approach problems like this in the future.